# What is the REST API URL to get "Linked Defects" from Test in ALM

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center

[image: ALM image]

I was not able to get the linked defects from the test, Is there a way to get it through REST API ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the Cross-Relations and approach it from the defects side:

```
.../defects?query={test.id[>=1 And NOT = 5]}
```

This one will give you all the defects that are connected to the tests with id 1-4.
More info on Cross-Filters [here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html#REST_API_Tech_Preview/General/Filtering.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use multiple query params to get the defects only for relevant test cycle with following request (otherwise I was fetching too many defects):

```
.../defects?query={test.id[12345];test-instance.id[6789012]}
```